# On Google App Engine in Python how do you detect if a JPEG uses CMYK color space and how do you convert it to RGB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jpeg

The Images API in Google App Engine does not appear to handle CMYK JPEG images properly when applying transforms. On the production server the resulting image looks washed out and on the dev server (where GAE uses PIL) the resulting image is darker and less defined.

It seems like the API assumes all JPEG files are RGB.

Is there a way to detect a CMYK image on Google App Engine?

Is there a way to convert the image to RGB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG can refer to both a format standard, [JIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), and the most widely-used complying implementation, [JFIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFIF).

Unfortunately, the Images API has no documented support for detection or conversion of JPEGs encoded using Adobe's CMYK-based format. Technically these are valid JPEGs, but support for the format seems to be extremely scant.

[hachoir-parser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-parser) supports [detecting CMYK JPEGs](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/src/f45d30cc82db/hachoir-parser/hachoir_parser/image/jpeg.py#cl-176) by parsing the binary stream. As long as it's pure python, it should work on App Engine.

You can request official support in the Images API on the [App Engine issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Comment: I have requested support on the issue tracker for detecting CMYK images. As it is a feature request with low interest I expect it will not be added, or at least not soon, unless it is really easy to do. I will have to look into an alternate solution like the hachoir-parser. I was hoping there was a simple way to detect CMYK without using a large external library. Thanks.

Comment: hachoir is not going to help apart from allowing you to reject cmyk images via an error to the user, since there is no way to get the Images api to respect the colourspace (handy to know about hachoir though!)